# Function pointer casting parameter to void

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers, calling-convention, reinterpret-cast

I wrote a simple demo(test.cpp) for my question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void* (*SEL)(void);

int foo(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c;
}

SEL _ptr_to_foo() {
    return (SEL)foo;
}
int main() {
    SEL sel = _ptr_to_foo();

    return 0;
}
```

and I compiled it with `g++ test.cpp -o test` in my osx and compilers complained nothing.

But I'm confused about what happened here. As my opinion,  `SEL` defines function pointer which parameter is `void` and returns `void*`. However, function `foo` should be a function which accepts three int parameters and returns an int as result. I think the function pointer of `foo` should be declared as something like `int (*ptr)(int, int, int) = foo;`. Why the casting in `_ptr_to_foo` works? What happened here?

Comment: "works" is relative. `SEL` is not compatible with `foo()`.

Comment: @Swordfish I tried to call my foo via SEL but failed because of the wrong parameter. It seems that SEL throws away my parameter information in foo. Does this mean your `not compatible` in your comment?

Comment: Why *should* the cast fail? Especially a c-style cast?

Comment: Why don't you just use the correct type?

Comment: clang and gcc both don't raise a warning but MSVC does: https://godbolt.org/z/jigfnq. Modern compilers are good but they can't catch every possible bug with a warning

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't think I get the point why this cast works. (int, int, int) cast to void?

Comment: It works because the C++ language allows it. It allows it because you may want to store a function pointer under a different type, and cast back later based on other information stored with it it.

Comment: Tell us **what you are trying to accomplish here**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c-style casts are fairly lax in their type checking. You should use `static_cast` instead. This fails to compile:

```
return static_cast<SEL>(foo);
```

Comment: Ok, this one fails. Should I reckon this c-style cast as a bug here?

Comment: No, it is not a bug, it is by design. Using a `reinterpret_cast<>` in C++ will allow you to do the same ... stupid thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can store function pointers as the wrong function pointer type.

If you call them as the wrong function pointer type the behaviour of your program becomes undefined by the C++ standard.

Your use of a C-style cast becomes a `reinterpret_cast<SEL>`, which can do very unsafe things.